# K Value not changing outcome for SelectKBest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am currently working on a project where I am running through data and trying to find the best features in the data. I am using sklearn and the SelectKBest module. When I run the code I get outcomes but no matter what K value I use it gives me the same results. Was wondering if anyone could look at my code and tell me what is wrong. I am building this using Jupyter Notebook so I will change the value and then rerun the block.

```
features_list = ['poi', 'salary','to_messages','deferral_payments',
                 'total_payments','exercised_stock_options','bonus',
                 'restricted_stock','shared_receipt_with_poi','restricted_stock_deferred',
                 'total_stock_value','expenses','loan_advances','from_messages','other',
                 'from_this_person_to_poi','director_fees','deferred_income','long_term_incentive','from_poi_to_this_person'] 

        data = featureFormat(data_dict, features_list, sort_keys=True)
            labels, features = targetFeatureSplit(data)

            from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest

            clf = SelectKBest()
            new_features = clf.fit_transform(features,labels)
            params = clf.get_params()

            i=0
            featureImportance = []
            for item in clf.scores_:
                featureImportance.append((item,features_list[i+1]))
                i=i+1

            featureImportance=sorted(featureImportance, reverse=True)
            for item in featureImportance:
                 print "{0} , {1:4.2f}%".format(item[1],item[0])
```

Output:

```
exercised_stock_options , 25.10%
total_stock_value , 24.47%
bonus , 21.06%
salary , 18.58%
deferred_income , 11.60%
long_term_incentive , 10.07%
restricted_stock , 9.35%
total_payments , 8.87%
shared_receipt_with_poi , 8.75%
loan_advances , 7.24%
expenses , 6.23%
from_poi_to_this_person , 5.34%
other , 4.20%
from_this_person_to_poi , 2.43%
director_fees , 2.11%
to_messages , 1.70%
deferral_payments , 0.22%
from_messages , 0.16%
restricted_stock_deferred , 0.06%
```

The % do not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scores_` are generated on complete features from the supplied `score_func` parameter in [`SelectKBest`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html):

> **score_func** : callable Function taking two arrays X and y, and
>   returning a pair of arrays (scores, pvalues) or a single array with
>   scores. Default is f_classif (see below “See also”). The default
>   function only works with classification tasks.

By default, `SelectKBest` will use [`f_classif`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif).

Since the features supplied to it dont change, so the score will not change. What will change is how many of these features are selected based on these scores. Based on the `k` value you chose, the top features will be selected.

You can see which features are selected using the [`get_support()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.get_support) method.